# Set element to Hidden when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm putting together this basic script for a site: http://jsfiddle.net/mcgarriers/rVPnu/2/

It works great when I select the various numbers (it shows the relevant divs) but when I go back to click "Select" it still displays the `<div>`s. I'd like it **if the user clicks "Select" that mySpecialElements is hidden again**.

Can someone show me how to achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I can't seem to follow the logic, sometimes you show 1 div, sometimes you show several divs. I am not clear on what exactly you are trying to to do witht his example.  The other thing to consider is instead of hand coding your logic you might want to use JQuery to do select listeners and element locators for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your script here: http://jsfiddle.net/rVPnu/6/.

```
 if(!value) hideAll(elementsContainer);
```

You need to check that value is not empty in the doSelect method and hideAll if it is.

Comment: Many thanks for taking a look and for such a speedy and correct reply,  Nathan. Just got to wait the 10minutes before green ticking you :-D

Answer (score 0):

Just interchange `hideAll(elementsContainer);` and `if (!targetDiv) { return;}` in your `doSelect` function.

I have saved this in: http://jsfiddle.net/rVPnu/9/

Answer (score 0):

Call `hideAll(elementsContainer);` before returning from `doSelect` method.

```
    // do magic..
    hideAll(elementsContainer);

    if (!targetDiv) { return;} // didn't find the element, bail
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/rVPnu/8/)**